70s to early 90s American or French Horror film where in the last scene a man turns into this pinkish blob and eats a fly
I hope somebody can help me with this. I saw this when I was quite young and the movie was giving me nightmares but I can't find it. That is the only thing I remember because it scared me to death.
The blob or whatever runs over a police officer perhaps or maybe he was security guard...and somehow the guy becomes a blob, and then likely in the last scene, he eyes a fly on his blob like body and and then snatches it, kind of like a frog or something. 
I looked up the movie Blob 1988 but that does not seem to be it.  

Could be Weird Science. The big brother gets turned into some kind of blob - think it was a big pile of poo - and snatches a fly that lands on him.

This is possibly the 1989 film The Fly II. The film ends on a shot of the villain, having been turned into a pinkish monstrosity, staring at a fly. He got transformed this way by having the main character, taken over by fly DNA and himself morphed into a fly-like monster, using the teleportation device he's been restoring to swap his mutant DNA for the villain's healthy human DNA.
